# Bootstrapping nodes and deploying without chef server

Tags: chef-infra, configuration-management

I'm looking to bootstrap some nodes and deploy to them, but I want to avoid having the overhead of a chef server. What are some of the options I can look into? I have a relatively static environment, but need to push some changes to the remote nodes every so often. I want to kick off a recipe to all the nodes from a host machine.

Comment: In that case, You can check with chef-solo or chef-zero but the overhead is you would have to push respective cookbook on the machine as this would be standalone operation.

Comment: So what exactly is the workflow at this point? Ideally, I run one command from a host node and it executes to all the other nodes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to use chef-server, you can use knife-solo from workstation. It has all the commands starting from initializing the chef-repo to converge on target node.

`knife solo init chef-repo`

Then, you can create `node.json` file in the nodes sub-directory of chef-repo which will contain your runlist.

Then, you bootstrap specific nodes via knife-solo from a central workstation, i.e,

`knife solo bootstrap ubuntu@172.0.0.1 nodes/node.json`

It will install chef-solo and then converge the run-list on the target node.

In case you want to only converge, it can be done via:

`knife solo cook ubuntu@172.0.0.1`

For more reference you can refer:

https://matschaffer.github.io/knife-solo/

http://markjberger.com/an-introduction-to-chef-solo/

Comment: Do you mind summing up in simple terms this process? I read this blog and it's still convoluted to me. Do I need to manually go into any of the nodes for any reason or can everything be done from a central workstation?

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: That's awesome, thank you. So, I'm in the unfortunate position of managing windows-only nodes. Is the bootstrap process the same? IP/User/Pass?

Comment: Go through the last section of knife solo docs, it has some windows support but with some manual steps.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run a recipe against a list of nodes from one source, you'll likely need to use an orchestration tool to assist in running/auditing these operations.

I can personally vouch for [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/). You'll need to do a bit of legwork to get rundeck to be able to ssh into each of your nodes, but once you've set it up it isn't difficult to create a rundeck job that runs chef-solo/chef-zero on any subset of those nodes you want it to.